# Prolog Recursion through a list

Tags: prolog

I want a predicate that goes through a list of lists and checks if each of those lists verify certain conditions, in case a list verifies the conditions, it gets added to ResultList (another list of lists). I wrote this:

```
mypredicate(ListOfLists, ReferenceList, ResultList) :-
    mypredicate(ListOfLists, ReferenceList, ResultList, []),

mypredicate([H|T], ReferenceList, ResultList, Acc) :-
    elementos_comuns(ReferenceList, H),
    H \== ReferenceList,
    append(Acc, H, ResultList),
    T \== [],
    mypredicate(T, ReferenceList, ResultList, ResultList).
```

I only want to append if both lines above "append" return true, and regardless of what happens in the first 3 lines, I want it to run the last line if T \== [].

The problem is that when it reaches an element of ListOfLists that doesn't verify one these two:

```
elementos_comuns(ReferenceList, H),
H \== ReferenceList,
```

the whole thing returns false.

I need ResultList to be a list of lists that contains the lists from "ListOfList" that verify

```
elementos_comuns(ReferenceList, H),
H \== ReferenceList,
```

I have no idea how to do this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you call `mypredicate` with some list `[A, B, C]`. It will check some conditions on `A`, then recurse with `[B, C]`. It will check some conditions on `B`, then recurse with `[C]`. It will check some conditions on `C`, but then, since `T` is now `[]`, it will fail at `T \== []`. Your predicate has no chance of succeeding while you have this condition. You should probably remove it, and add another clause of the form `mypredicate([], ..., ..., ...)`.

Even then your predicate will only be able to handle cases where all the conditions are satisfied. It will fail as soon as you run it on a list where `elementos_comuns/2` fails.

There are three distinct situations you want to handle:

- empty list
- list `[H | T]` where `H` satisfies the `elementos_comuns/2` check
- list `[H | T]` where `H` does not satisfy the `elementos_comuns/2` check

A predicate that wants to handle three distinct cases should usually consist of three clauses.